# Select non-empty string rows in KDB

Tags: kdb

```
q)tab

items sales prices detail
-------------------------
nut   6     10     "blah"    
bolt  8     20     ""
cam   0     15     "some text"    
cog   3     20     ""    
nut   6     10     ""    
bolt  8     20     ""
```

I would like to select only the rows which have "detail" non-empty. Seems fairly straightforward, but not i can't get it to work.

```
q) select from tab where count[detail] > 0
```

This gives all the rows still.

Alternatively i tried

```
q) select from tab where not null detail
```

This gives me type error.

How can one query for non-empty string fields in KDB???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than use adverbs, you can simplify this with the use of [like](https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/like).

```
q)select from tab where not detail like ""

  items sales prices detail
  ------------------------------
  nut   1     10     "blah"
  cam   5     9      "some text"
```

Answer (score 1):

As you need to perform the check row-wise, use `each`:

```
select from tab where 0 < count each detail
```

This yields to the following table:

```
items sales prices detail     
------------------------------
nut   6     10     "blah"     
cam   0     15     "some text"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the adverb each:

```
q)select from ([]detail:("blah";"";"some text")) where 0<count each detail
detail     
-----------
"blah"     
"some text"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use following approach

```
select from tab where not detail~\:""
```

where every detail is compared to empty string. Approach with `not null detail` does not work, because Q treats string as character array and checks if each of array elements is null. I.e. `null "abc"` returns boolean array `000b`, but where clause expects for single boolean value for each "row"

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. Now i understand underlying construct better.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is not big, another way you can check is by converting it to a `symbol` in the `where` clause.

```
q)select from ([]detail:("blah";"";"some text")) where `<>`$detail 
detail
-----------
"blah"
"some text"
```

Or simply

```
q)select from ([]detail:("blah";"";"some text")) where not null `$detail 
detail
-----------
"blah"
"some text"
```